# Rally Ext JS change functionalty of existing component

Tags: extjs, rally, appsdk2

I am trying to either override or extend an existing component - the [Rally.ui.PercentDone](https://prod.help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc1/doc/source/PercentDone.html#Rally-ui-PercentDone) component.  I want to provide it with a portfolio item with all the data necessary to render it using the same color coding Rally native apps use (the Rally [Health Color Calculator](https://prod.help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc1/doc/source/HealthColorCalculator.html#Rally-util-HealthColorCalculator)).

I really just need the function to pass the correct record.  Here is my idea so far:

```
Ext.define('Custom.PercentDone', {
    requires: ['Rally.ui.renderer.template.progressbar.PortfolioItemPercentDoneTemplate', 'Rally.util.HealthColorCalculator'],
    extend  : 'Rally.ui.PercentDone',
    alias   : 'widget.cpercentdone',


    config: {
        record: null
    },

    constructor: function(config) {
        config = this.config;
        this.renderTpl = Ext.create('Custom.renderer.template.progressbar.PercentDoneTemplate', {
            calculateColorFn: Ext.bind(function(recordData) {
                console.log('called my custom coloring fn');
                var colorObject = Rally.util.HealthColorCalculator.calculateHealthColorForPortfolioItemData(config.record, config.percentDoneName);
                return colorObject.hex;
            }, this)
        });
        this.renderData = config;
        this.mergeConfig(config);
        this.callParent([this.config]);
    }
});

var custom = Ext.create('Custom.PercentDone', {
    record: item,
    percentDoneName: 'PercentDoneByStoryPlanEstimate',
});
```

but my calculate color function is not being called instead of the default.

I got it to work by overriding:

```
            var percentDoneByStoryCountEl = Ext.create("Rally.ui.PercentDone", {
                record: item,
                percentDoneName: "PercentDoneByStoryCount",
                percentDone: item.PercentDoneByStoryCount
            });
            tpl = percentDoneByStoryCountEl.renderTpl;
            tpl.calculateColorFn = function (recordData) {
                var colorObject = Rally.util.HealthColorCalculator.calculateHealthColorForPortfolioItemData(item, "PercentDoneByStoryCount");
                return colorObject.hex;
            };

            Ext.override(percentDoneByStoryCountEl, {
                renderTpl: tpl
            });
```

but I would like to figure out how to do it via extending the component instead.

Thanks for your help.